# Example of a continuous function which is bounded and not contained in any $L_p$-space ($p\gt 0$)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

I'm struggling to find an example of a continuous function $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ which is bounded, not contained in any $L_p$-space ($p\gt 0$) and goes to zero when x goes to infinity.

I need help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $p = \infty$, then it's clearly not bounded.

Comment: @user40276 yes, p is finite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider 
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\log(x+3)}
$$

Comment: this function is continuous?

Comment: as composition of continuous on $(0,+\infty)$ functions

Comment: Are you talking about the composition of (1,1/log x) with the min function?

Comment: @user : He's saying that $f(x,y) = \min \{x,y\}$ is a continuous function, hence since $1$ and $1/\log(x)$ are continuous, so is $f(x) = \min \{ 1, 1/\log(x)\}$.

Comment: @user42912 If you want $\min(a,b)=(a+b-|a-b|)/2$. So it is indeed a composition of continuous functions.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva yes yes, of course

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva why he didn't choose min(1,1/x)?

Comment: It seems your function is in the $L^p$ space.

Comment: @user42912 : He wanted to keep the function bounded, the function $1/log(x)$ has the right behavior at infinity (i.e. the integral of the tail diverges whatever power of $p$ you put it to), but not the right behavior around $0$ (the function is not bounded). So Norbert kept the interesting part of his example and got rid of the non-interesting part using the minimum.

Comment: How about $f(x) = 1/\log(3+x)$ ? This discussion of the minimus is besides the point.

Comment: @user42912 Sorry I had to go so I was not able to explain in details. Thanks to other visitors for their kind explanations.

Comment: @HansEngler Yes it is more simpler. I'll this example.

Comment: @Norbert thank you for your help!

Comment: @HansEngler : That's another way of getting rid of the problem. One way or the other works just fine, but I like better the intuition of "bounding the function" by literally setting a boundary for where it "can live". Moving log around is quite ad hoc compared to the intuition of bounding the function.

Comment: Speaking of irrelevant, the number $3$ has nothing to do with this example ; $1/\log(x+a)$ with $a > 0$ would work just fine, I don't know why you felt like $3$ was your lucky number! Maybe it had to do with $e$...

Comment: @Patrick - $1/log(x+a)$ with $a > 1$, in order to avoid a singularity at $x = 1-a$. :)

Comment: @HansEngler : I admit I answered a bit quick but that was what I had in mind. Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Another example is $f:(1,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}x^{-1/n}.$$